# Merging training points for classification (Random Forest) using L9 data in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, google

I am not able to merge training points using Google Earth Engine code. I am very new to Google Earth Engine.

The code which is tried is

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2")
.filterDate('2022-01-01','2022-05-30') //LO09_L1TP_144051_20230228_20230307_02_T1
.filterBounds(roi) 
.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 5);
//applies scaling factors
function applyScalFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands=image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands,null,true).addBands(opticalBands,null,true);
}

var rescale = dataset.map(applyScalFactors);
var image = rescale.median();
var visualization = {
  bands:  ['SR_B4','SR_B3','SR_B2'],
  min:0.0,
  max:0.3,
  
};


Map.addLayer(image,visualization,'Landsat 9');
Map.centerObject(roi);

var training = barren.merge(forest).merge(water).merge(urban).merge(crop);
print(training)
```

I have collected training data and assigned to below shown in classes :

```
var roi = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Point(),
    water = /* color: #3c2cce */ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(
        [[
    urban = /* color: #ecff31 */ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(
        [,
    crop = /* color: #00ff00 */ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(
        [
       
    barren = /* color: #ff33b0 */ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(
        ;
```

The error is Line 26: barren.merge is not a function
one more error `unrecognised arguments scale to function Image.sampleRegions` Line34
what is the mistake , can anyone suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
var training = barren.merge(forest).merge(water).merge(urban).merge(crop);
```

You need to cast explicitly **barren** class as a Feature Collection as follows:

```
var training = ee.FeatureCollection(barren).merge(forest).merge(water).merge(urban).merge(crop);
```

So, to test my approach, I created arbitrarily a roi in USA where your training points contain only one point for each class. This can be observed in complete code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3814b68515c6a714645c5fb754b7f993) and in following lines:

```
var water = ee.Geometry.Point([-119.32151600599221, 46.989076764802405]),
    urban = ee.Geometry.Point([-119.16133873346475, 46.82231185837929]),
    crop = ee.Geometry.Point([-119.38517312129844, 46.903765509905014]),
    barren = ee.Geometry.Point([-119.29642418941367, 46.88476221931775]),
    forest = ee.Geometry.Point([-118.13371248864892, 45.94253324235733]),

    roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-119.72904080257975, 47.200648227651364],
          [-119.72904080257975, 45.885916077398704],
          [-117.76248806820475, 45.885916077398704],
          [-117.76248806820475, 47.200648227651364]]], null, false);

Map.centerObject(roi);
Map.setOptions("SATELLITE");

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2")
.filterDate('2022-01-01','2022-05-30') //LO09_L1TP_144051_20230228_20230307_02_T1
.filterBounds(roi) 
.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 5);
//applies scaling factors
function applyScalFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands=image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands,null,true).addBands(opticalBands,null,true);
}

var rescale = dataset.map(applyScalFactors);
var image = rescale.median();
var visualization = {
  bands:  ['SR_B4','SR_B3','SR_B2'],
  min:0.0,
  max:0.3,
  
};


Map.addLayer(image,visualization,'Landsat 9');
Map.centerObject(roi);

var training = ee.FeatureCollection(barren).merge(forest).merge(water).merge(urban).merge(crop);
print(training);
```

After running it at GEE code editor, I got following result without any issue.

[image]

Comment: Tank you it worked